# How to Stop Scrolling in Wheel Picker when i select the past time in it?

Tags: java, android, ios, scroll, datetimepicker

I have implemented the custom wheel Picker which is similar to ios wheel picker.
When the page loads the wheel picker is getting the current time upto here its fine.
But i `don't want to scroll` the wheel picker if i select the `previous time` say  current time is
Aug 5 mon 10:52 PM if i select aug 5 mon 10:50 pm also it wont scroll.And also background should be disabled.

#### Please provide a solution.

Implemented the code:

```
if(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR) ==0){ 
    hours.setCurrentItem(11);
    }else{
                hours.setCurrentItem(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR)-1);
        }
        mins.setCurrentItem(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        ampm.setCurrentItem(calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM));
```

This coding implemented when i change the wheel picker and if i click done button in it then it moves to the current time i want not by clicking actions if i change the time as previous time then there should be no change in the wheel picker.